# Performance impact of type conversion from empty interface (dynamic) to static type in golang

Tags: go

Does converting an empty interface to type have any performance impact?

```
var generic interface{}
generic = 34
i = d.(int)
```

Does this conversion has any impact on performance? 
I am working on in-memory cache using map, my definition of map goes like this

```
cache map[interface{}]interface{}
```

The above map is more generic than the below implementation

```
cache map[string][]byte
```

I want to know if there will be any performance hit by using generic and converting them back. Any reference documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: Conversion to `interface{}` requires an allocation for values larger than a machine word.  A `string` is larger than a machine word.  An allocation is not required for a conversion from `interface{}` to a concrete type.

Comment: So using `cache map[string][]byte` is a better idea?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just benchmark it if you want to know the exact numbers for your case. And no, there is no reference documentation that specifies that a such a conversion will take at least x nanoseconds and at most y nanoseconds.

Comment: What will go into the []byte content of the cache? Are you planning to somehow encode the data into []byte? If so, that'll be slow. If you want to cache generic values with a key, the fastest is probably map[string]interface{}.

Comment: if I have `type custom string`, `var s1 custom = "abc"` ,`s1 == "abc"` return true. But does it require more compute/time to do this?